# Pourquoi « je m'en rappelle » est-il incorrect ?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, verbes

Récemment, j'ai entendu dire que la phrase suivante est incorrecte :

> Je m'en rappelle.

A l'oreille, cette phrase ne me choque pas, sûrement car on l'entend souvent. Savez-vous pourquoi elle est incorrecte ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dans le cas de l’emploi transitif, on emploie « rappeler quelque chose à quelqu’un » et non pas « rappeler quelqu’un de quelque chose », comme le constate le [TLFi, acception I. C](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/rappeler). « *<strike>Je t’en rappelle</strike> » est clairement fautif ; on dit « Je te le rappelle ».

L’emploi pronominal est normalement identique. Cependant, le même [TLFi, III. A. a. α)](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/rappeler) admet que l’emploi calqué sur *se souvenir de* existe. La 14<sup>e</sup> édition du Bon Usage, §285 9<sup>o</sup> constate son emploi à l’oral, mais sa rareté à l’écrit.

En deux mots, l’emploi est répandu à l’oral mais on peut vouloir l’éviter.

Comment: "on peut vouloir" c'est un belgicisme?

Comment: J’ai tendance à croire que non, mais je suis belge.

Comment: Cela semble vraiment un combat d'arrière-garde tant cet usage est répandu.